# jQuery Tabs - Unable to trap tab click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to trap the jQuery tab click event as follows:

```
$('#statisticsTab').tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        alert("In activate!");

        var $activeTab = $('#statisticsTab').tabs('option', 'active');
        if ($activeTab === 1) {
            alert("Tab 1 is active!");
        }
        else if ($activeTab === 2) {
            alert("Tab 2 is active!");
        }
        else if ($activeTab === 3) {
            alert("Tab 3 is active!");
        }
    }
});
```

The tab control itself works perfectly but none of the alerts in this code ever fire when I click on the various tabs. I'm using jQuery 1.10.2.

Comment: Can you create live demo/fiddle. It'll be easier to work on that.

Comment: @Tushar - don't you see my Alert (that says 'In Activate') inside the activate function? It never fires.

Comment: I tried your example http://jsfiddle.net/9ChL5/1/ it should work (even if it can be improved a bit though). Could it be the browser popups are disabled or something?

Comment: @Wilmer - Your fiddle helped me identify what was wrong. If you want to wrap this in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad to help I actually tested with your code but somehow forgot to update the actual fiddle, find the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per request of the OP here's a slightly improved version and the fiddle that helped identify the problem:

```
$('#statisticsTab').tabs({
activate: function (event, ui) {
    alert("In activate!");

    var $activeTab = ui.newTab.index();
    if ($activeTab === 1) {
        alert("Tab 1 is active!");
    }
    else if ($activeTab === 2) {
        alert("Tab 2 is active!");
    }
    else if ($activeTab === 3) {
        alert("Tab 3 is active!");
    }
}
```

});

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9ChL5/145/)